# Robospice, проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: java, android, кодировка, robospice

Создаю класс, в котором формирую руками xml, т.е. теги захардкодены, значения полей это переменные, которые инициализирую.

Перед тем как отправить запрос на сервер, вывожу результат в лог (перед блоком инициализации `messageConverters`), и вижу, что данные корректны. Но на сервер не все данные приходят корректно, часть кириллицы приходит в виде `?????`.

В чем может быть проблема с моей стороны?

```
private MyResponse execute() throws Exception {
    Ssl ssl = new Ssl();
    setRetryPolicy(ssl.buildRetryPolicy());

    getRestTemplate().setRequestFactory(ssl.buildRequestFactory());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

    List<Charset> charsets = new ArrayList<>();
    charsets.add(Charset.forName("utf-8"));

    headers.setAcceptCharset(charsets);
    headers.setAuthorization(new HttpAuthentication() {

        @Override
        public String getHeaderValue() {
            return "Bearer " + mToken;
        }
    });

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(mParams.getXml(), headers);


    getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().clear();
    getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
    getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().add(new XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter());

    return getRestTemplate().postForObject(mParams.getUrl(), request, MyResponse.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Решило проблему:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "xml", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```